# Passing instance of a class in js and accessing their methods without new instance

Tags: javascript, es6-class

```
class A{
  constructor(name){
     this[name] = name ; //to be private so i need this
     new B(this);
  }
  getName(){
    return this[name];
  }
}
class B(){
  constructor(a){
     a.getName()// I wants to be like this
  }
}
```

I just want to call the methods without creating a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make private data in a class, either use a WeakMap or a closure. `this[name]` is not private at all, it's completely visible to anything that has access to the instantiated object.

Another problem is that with your `return this[name];`, the `getName` function does not have the `name` variable in scope.

Also, an object's class methods can't be accessed before the object itself is instantiated.

You might want something like this instead:

```js
const A = (() => {
  const internals = new WeakMap();
  return class A {
    constructor(name) {
      internals.set(this, { name });
    }
    getName() {
      return internals.get(this).name;
    }
  }
})();
class B {
  constructor(a) {
    console.log(a.getName())
  }
}

const a = new A('bob');
const b = new B(a);
```